# Best method to automate across platforms

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

On a daily basis I edit G code to be run on a CO2 laser and I must remove the same string from every file before running it. Currently I open each file in notepad and do ctrl + h and replace it that way. I am looking for a more efficient way to do it.

I am given a packet with a run number (ie 123456), and that run number corresponds to a directory on the network. In that directory are a number of .txt or .nc files that require the string to be removed.

Each run directory is contained in a file structure that looks like this

"\\server\x\companyname\123456"

In \companyname\ there could be hundreds of run directories, all 6 digits - these are the run numbers and are different for each case. I would like to be able to create a program that prompts me for the the run number, and then finds that directory in \x, or rather the complete path as \companyname changes based on the run number, and then replace the string in each file within the \123456 directory. So if the string is Y11 and I was given the run number 000001, I would be prompted for the run number, it would search for the directory and set the path to \\server\x\walmart\000001\ and search each file in this directory for the string Y11 and delete it.

I tried using powershell and was able to find the run folder using Prompt and get-childitem using -recurse and setting a prompted variable to use for -include, however the system doesn't allow scripts!

I can't run scripts because it's a work computer. It says the execution of scripts are disabled on this system. Basically get-executionpolicy is set to restricted and I don't have a cert for this.

This is the code i have so far

```
$Run = Read-Host prompt "What is the run number?"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\\server\x\" -Filter "$Run" -recurse
foreach ($file in $files)
   (Get-object $file.PSPath) | 
   Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "G33", ""} |
   Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

The last portion starting with foreach is something I copied and pasted off a previous example. I have very little experience with powershell. So the run number is located in a directory two levels below x\, for and when the user is prompted for the run number I want it to search all of x, locate the path including the directory that contains the run number (walmart in the example above), and then get all the files in the run number folder. Those files would have a path like

\server\x\walmart\000001\118000001_01.NC

There can be many files in this run folder, and they all need to have the string G33 removed from them.

I am new to this, can someone please explain step by step using powershell, visual basic or any method you think would be the easiest? Even java! I am hoping to be able to use this across PCs with different operating systems. Mostly windows. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the PowerShell code you've tried so far. Are you saying that you can run commands interactively, but your system is configured not to allow calling scripts (via `Set-ExecutionPolicy`)?

Comment: Please expand on "the system doesn't allow scripts". If you get an error please post it. What kind of system is this - windows? Do you have administrator access? If you don't you can probably use VBScript to do this as it requires less privileges

Comment: The powershell ise is installed on the system, but unfortunately I don't have admin privileges. I can execute commands line by line but when I try to run my script I get the error (I will post my exact code and the error tomorrow when I'm back in the office).

Comment: The middle 95% of this seems mostly fine, although at the current juncture it seems like it all boils down to "the execution of scripts are disabled on this system."  As for the title and last paragraph, those are very opinion-based and broad, respectively, which would be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  You're either committed to a particular language or you're not, and no one here can make a better determination than you which one that should be.  If you don't have experience or a predisposition to one or the other, that might make things...challenging.

Comment: I am open to using any language.  At this point I am a mechanical engineer wishing he had taken computer science and become a developer!!! For this particular case, I am able to create .bat files and Its possible that I could get my admin privileges elevated.  However, I was able to install python on the system, but nobody here has mention that as being an ideal way of doing this.  Again, I am a super newb, so any suggestions are welcome.  Thank you for not pwning me so far.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is having an administrator for that server run PowerShell's `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` commandlet, so that local PowerShell scripts can be executed.  Note that on Windows 64-bit, this might need to be done from both a 64-bit PowerShell prompt and from a 32-bit PowerShell prompt, to ensure local PowerShell scripts could be executed from either PowerShell.

Another approach is to use sed (short for Stream Editor), a classic Unix utility that is available on Linux, macOS and Windows.  For the latter, search Google for UnixUtils on SourceForge, which includes sed and several other classic Unix utilities built for Windows.  Sed can do global search-and-replace within text files.  It is non-interactive and meant to be executed from a script (or Batch File).

A VBScript can also read each text file and do search-and-replace.  You can open the text file and using a loop read each line.  If a line contains the search string, replace that text (optionally with nothing) and then write it; otherwise write it unmodified.  You write to a temp file in the same path as the file you're reading, and when done you delete the original and rename the new temp file to the original file name.  You have to do error checking all along the way.

As for locating the sub-folders by Run Number, you can probably do that with a batch file (or bash script on Linux and macOS).  Something like this:

```
@echo off

:get-directory-list
dir \\server\x /S /B /AD /OGNE > "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ListOfDirectories.txt"

:prompt-runnumber
SET RUNNUMBER=
SET /P RUNNUMBER= Enter the 6-digit run number: 
if not defined RUNNUMBER echo invalid input & goto prompt-runnumber
if /i "%RUNNUMBER%" EQU "q" goto :EOF

:get-dir-for-run-number
type "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ListOfDirectories.txt" | find "%RUNNUMBER%" > nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Run Number not found & goto prompt-runnumber
type "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ListOfDirectories.txt" | find "%RUNNUMBER%" > %TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
set /P RUNFOLDER= < "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"   
echo Run Folder full path is %RUNFOLDER%

:process-files-in-folder
for %%i in (%RUNFOLDER%\*.*) do (
    echo Processing folder %RUNFOLDER%, file %%i
    rem ... run sed, VBscript, etc. to edit file
)
```

You might have to edit the above batch file to use a mapped drive letter.  For bash, you'd have to first mount the network share and refer to the mount point "directory".

bash offers corresponding commands to list directories, sort them, search for text strings (using grep rather than find), prompting for input, reading input from text files, etc.  Both Windows Batch and bash support sub-routines (batch files can call themselves and pass a label as a parameter) if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the taking the time to write this out.  What would you recommend as a resource to learn to write batch files?  For instance I don't even know the syntax or the identifiers necessary to create the file.  I am currently trying to learn python, Visual Basic and C, and have a very loose grasp on Matlab but that is mostly for optimization.  Any suggestions for learning to code in basically all languages or being fluent across the most formats would be most appreciated.

Comment: There is an online guide to Windows Batch Files here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting.  Another good site is https://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php.  From the Command Prompt in Windows, the command help is worth reading, e.g. FOR /?, IF /?, SET /? etc.  But Python or PowerShell are far more powerful, and they're available on Windows, Linux and macOS.  Whatever script language you choose, take the time to understand how to search strings, 'escape' special characters and use single or double quotes when necessary (esp. for file/dir paths that may contain spaces).

Comment: Everyone is biased to their favourite language, but I would recommend learning Powershell over batch. There's just too much that is impossible or insanely difficult in batch that is easy in Powershell

Comment: I wouldn't avoid learning batch and bash, as they are very handy.  My rule of thumb is to script using batch/bash unless the task is demanding (e.g. text/XML/CSV file processing, or needing to maintain hash tables or dictionaries).  I use PowerShell or Python for these more complex scripts.